# Authenticode checking slows .NET build

Tags: build, performance, code-signing

In other posts, e.g.

[Why are signed assemblies slow to load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618596/why-are-signed-assemblies-slow-to-load/2059410#2059410)

it is shown how to avoid checking of signed assemblies when an app runs in a non- or slow-connected environment, by using the generatePublisherEvidence tag in the app's config file.

Good for the app users, but what about the developer? It seems my app *builds* very slowly under the same circumstances, and the config file approach doesn't help. Is there a relevant project build setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I found the answer, but I thought it would be good to have it posted here. At the link

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/bc778e26-9156-4924-a9ca-a57ef8ff6bcc/

"Robbie Couret" wrote:

```
 In Internet Explorer 7...

 Tools->Internet Options->Advanced->Security Node,
 Uncheck 'Check for publisher's certificate revocation*'
```

Yes this, really did speed up my builds from 90 seconds to 3 seconds. (My app uses several signed, third party assemblies.)

Martin

Answer (score 0):

I can only tell you what we do at work. The developer build don't sign the assemblies, it is only the "official build machine" that has the code signing certificate installed. So the developer is not required to have a open internet connection to VeriSign or whatever to do the signing.

The build script checks for the existence of an environment variable that points to a certificate. If you don't have the certificate, no signing.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I wasn't more clear on this, the problem for me is with commercial, third party assemblies.