# Location of app.config file in a windows service project?

Tags: vb.net, wcf, visual-studio-2010, windows-services

I am creating a windows service in VS2010, and in order to store a user's input during installation I've been told to write it to a file called app.config.

However i cannot find this app.config file? Does it create one in a windows service project? or just in a WCF windows service project?

Comment: dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916023/app-config-vs-appname-exe-config

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VS do the following:

- Click on the service project
- And add new item
- Select Application Configuration File.

This will appear in your service project as `app.config`.

When you actually build the project you'll see it a `Spotter.exe.config` along side your `Spotter.exe` file.

Comment: And it can be added to any project.

Comment: true it's called Web.Config and not renamed since there's no EXE(?) there.