# Running C# like java

Tags: c#

Running java in batch would look like this

@ECHO OFF
java -Xmx512m -Xms512m -jar "PROGRAM.jar"
PAUSE

that would give it 512mb of ram. How could I do that in C#?

Comment: Just generate an EXE and double click on it.

Comment: Are you asking "how do I run a C# application from the command line?" or "how do I limit the available memory for a C# application which is started from the command line?"

Comment: By the way, what in the world do you mean by "give it 512 MB of RAM"? Give it? A C# program consumes the memory it needs, which is usually much lower than that, depending on what your application is doing.

Comment: @HighCore He is talking about memory allocation for the Java VM. The Java program then works within that memory footprint limit. I don't remember the specifics. Edit: He's setting initial and Max Heap size to 512mb in that command.

Comment: @Xenophile what happens when/if the limit is reached?

Comment: We used to have some Java applets that were embedded in pages for OLAP Data analysis and they would crash if I remember right when max configured heap size was exceeded.

Comment: @Xenophile right, so you can configure a java program to crash `on purpose` with a despotic and arbitrary memory limit? awesome...

Comment: Removing the `[java]` as the answer won't have anything to do with Java.

Answer (score 2):

The compiled .exe file from c# has a header, which can be executed by the windows shell, with double click, as how you would start Java in command line, but the command line it would be saved into a bat file. It is very different from a native, win32 exe. It needs a Java like virtual machine, just the runtime compilation is different.

There are many options how to give launch and runtime parameters, one of is the config file.  Please take a look [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916023/app-config-vs-appname-exe-config).

Answer (score 2):

Use Windows [Job Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684161.aspx) API.
Jobs can limit memory usage and process priority.

Comment: Very cool API, never knew about it. Best first post I have ever seen on SO.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 interpretations of your question as currently written:

1 - If you need to call a C# application from the command line / batch file just

- Generate an EXE (such as a Console Application)
- Call it directly by its filename (for example `C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe`)

2 - Limiting the amount of memory a certain program may consume is a bad idea.

- Make sure your application only consumes the neccesary memory by writing good code.
- I'm not aware of a mechanism that will limit the amount of memory a given .Net application can consume. And if it were such a thing, it's still a bad idea. Whenever the application reached that limit it would simply crash with an `OutOfMemoryException`.