# Signed assemblies loads too slow

Tags: c#, .net, performance, .net-assembly, signed

I have an application that contains only signed assemblies - addin for SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio).

This addin loads too slow.

According [Why are signed assemblies slow to load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618596/why-are-signed-assemblies-slow-to-load) such behavior is because of how security check works and for executable can be fixed by creation of config file with generatePublisherEvidence  attribute set to "false".

But i don't have any executables, only set of DLLs.

How can I disable the signature verification for DLLs?

I don't want to modify config for SSMS.

Comment: A dll is an executable.

Comment: @paqogomez yes but does creating a app.config file for it behave the same?

Comment: I tried <assembly>.dll.config and <assembly>.exe.config - no luck.

Comment: Assemblies don't have config files - applications do. You'll need to change the config for the hosting .exe.