# .Net Assembly signing and Certificate Revocation List check

Tags: c#, .net, strongname, assembly-signing

I recently came across a performance issue where - in a certain job engine though there are no queued jobs the first job takes a little longer to start. On investigation it was found out that the test machine was not internet connected and did not occur on subsequent job unless there is certain time lapse after the last job run.

One of my friend suggested that the delayed start is due to CRL check.

Does assemblies signed using certificates goes through Certificate Revocation List check before they get loaded into memory?

If so, what is the frequency of such check and how to disable.

Comment: Disconnect from Internet and find the answer.

Comment: It works well whether offline or online. I'm trying to understand how a strongly signed assembly (with certificate) is validated for authenticity (whether it has been tampered or not).

Comment: Looks like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1618596/15498) covers a lot of the same ground

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever. The reference helped me clarify all my doubts and how to address the issue.